# Javascript access to dynamodb via cognito with different regions

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

My cognito region is Tokyo (ap-northeast-1), while DynamoDB is set up in Sydney (ap-southeast-2). The problem I have is that if I configure

```
AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-1';
```

Then I can access the credentials, but then AWS assumes that my database is in the same region and I get:

```
POST https://dynamodb.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

If I configure

```
AWS.config.region = "ap-southeast-2";
```

Then I get:

```
OPTIONS https://cognito-identity.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Presumably because the identity cannot be found.

Now Cognito is only available in 3 regions, none of which correspond to any of the resources I have.

So how do I use both at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the SDK's global config set for Cognito's region and use [Service specific configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html#Service-Specific_Configuration) to instantiate the service clients for other regions.

```
//Set global region
AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-1';

//Get identity and credentials from Cognito

//Get dynamo db region specific client
var dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: "ap-southeast-2"});
```